# How do I have differing URLs for each environment (local/dev/test/prod) using Azure Oauth App Registrations

Tags: java, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have a Java Spring Boot web application that I am working on deploying and using Azure AD (Office365) as the user repository for Oauth.  The application will not be deployed in Azure.  I have the application working locally with the 'Home Page URL' set to http://localhost:8080.  It authenticates properly and I have no problems there.  My question is that how do I keep my localhost setting, in the app registration and add test or prod URL's along with that localhost URL for local development in the Azure App Registration?

I have used Google's Oauth stuff before and it has the ability to use multiple URL's for each app, solving this issue.  I realize that it is possible to make an app registration per environment, but that seems excessive.  Is there something I am not seeing or am I viewing this config incorrectly? Looking at the docs, it only mentions one URL for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the callback URLs for each environment in the Reply URLs section.
That allows authentication tokens to be returned to those URLs.

Then in your app, configure the `redirect_uri` parameter to be the current environment's callback URL.

The home page URL AFAIK is shown on some pages like the My Apps portal (myapps.microsoft.com), and it makes sense that if they want to link to your app from somewhere, only one URL is allowed for that.
If you use one registration, then this should be your production URL.
You can also use separate registrations for the different environments.

Comment: This works as I have set the callback to be per environment.  Tested localhost vs 127.0.0.1 host in URL.  I didn't not have to directly worry about **redirect_uri** in my app, as Spring Boot with Oauth2 seems to default to the current environment.  Thanks!